# How to add simple php or java function result into page or block?

Tags: magento2, php, blocks

How to add simple php or java function result into page or block using the page builder? If not possible please advise on other ways. I'm new with Magento.
I am writing a description of services provided. It is related to CGNAT. Would be good for reader to be displayed their external IP address. That could be done with simple function php code like:

```
<?php
//whether ip is from share internet
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
$ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
//whether ip is from proxy
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
$ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
//whether ip is from remote address
else
{
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
echo 'Your IP address is ';
echo  $ip_address;
if (str_starts_with ($ip_address, '100'))
{
echo '. It starts with 100, that means you are behind CGNAT.';
}
else
echo '. It does not appear like starts with 100. To be sure, you can logon into your 
router and check internet connection status. ';
?>
```

It is working if a php file placed in pub directory and called directly, but not working if the code itself or attempt to call the file placed inside page or block, like:

```
<?php include 'ipaddress.php';?>
```

Looks like no code or scripts are working at all. That one does nothing ether:

```
 <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

How it supposed to be done correctly?
Also would appreciate more reliable code for spotting CGNAT.

Comment: try it like this - require '../pub/OauthClient.php';

Comment: @Pramod looks like it's php code, block editor says "HTML code must be valid, all CSS & JavaScript must be wrapped in their HTML elements.". I think it implies php code is not allowed.